Should I include high school IB diploma on CV/resume?
I graduated high school with an IB diploma. I am a current undergraduate and I am wondering: Should I include high school IB diploma on CV/resume?
I have read this question, so I am essentially asking the question: is an IB diploma valuable enough to put on my CV/resume?
I think if I were a graduate student or above the answer would be clearly no.

This question would be improved for future readers by defining what an “IB diploma” is.

Well I guess that answers my question…

I included that I was an IB student when I was applying to Georgia State in 2015. And, while I still was, the academic or industry job I'm applying for won't care about that, so I omit it from my vita, since it isn't relevant to the position I currently want.
